# memcached multiple mysql results

Tags: php, mysql, memcached, store

I'm trying to set up memcached to store the results of the query that pulls all the data to be shown on my front page.  when i use memcached for one result it works fine, but when I set the query to 'LIMIT 10' and pull the cache it still only shows one result when I var_dump.

Is there something that I am missing? Or am I really only able to store one row at a time?

My basic syntax is as follows (result is assuming key has been set):

```
$sql = "select * from active limit 10"; 
//create an index key for memcache
$key = md5('query'.$sql); 
$result = $memcache->get($key);
var_dump($result);
```

edit: added entire code i am trying to work with

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) or die ("Could not connect"); 
$sql = "select * from active limit 10";

$key = md5('query'.$sql); 
$result = $memcache->get($key);

if($result == null) {
 $qry = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()." : $sql");

if(mysql_num_rows($qry)> 0) {
$result = mysql_fetch_object($qry);
echo "THIS IS NOT CACHE<br>";
var_dump($result);
//store it
$memcache->set($key,$result,0,10);
    }
}
else {
echo "this is cached<br>";
var_dump($result);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the complete code sample, your missing the query execution and how you are retrieving the data and setting it in the cache.

Comment: According to what you posted, all your caching is the sql statement.

Comment: @DigitalPrecision i have added the entire snippet to the question above

Comment: One comment, it looks like your cache is only valid for 10 seconds. Is this long enough?

Comment: @hafichuk that was just for testing purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through your results, I'd recommend this:

```
$cachedResults = $memcache->get($key);

if (!empty($cachedResults)) {
    var_dump(unserialize($cachedResults));
    exit;
}

$qry = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()." : $sql");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($qry)) {
    $results[] = $row;
}

$memcache->set($key, serialize($results));
```

Remember, if you already have the key in cache, then it will never hit the query to reload the correct result set, so flush it first, then try this code snippet.

Comment: our of curiosity, why is it necessary to serialize the results?

Comment: serialize() just flattens the array into a string format, which means you will be able to store the entire result set into memcached, if you don't serialize you will only cache the first result of the result set.

Answer (score 1):

You are using:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_object($qry);
```

which only retrieve a single record from the database.

What you need to do is loop through and build an array of objects:

```
while ($result[] = mysql_fetch_object($qry));
```

which you can then serialize and cache.

Your code should then look something like this:

```
...
if($result == null) {
  $qry = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()." : $sql");

  while ($result[] = mysql_fetch_object($qry));

  // cache it
  $memcache->set($key,serialize($result),0,10);
}
...
```